# declare var variable versus using self

Tags: javascript, scope

A bit of confusion. Here's the JS code:

```
(function(){
    var self = this;
    var view = 12;

    self.value = null;

    .... 
});
```

I understand using var view = 12 creates a local scope for the view variable. But doesn't self.value also create a "local" scope for the value variable? If so, what is the difference or am I missing something?

Comment: `self.value = ...` simply creates a **property** on the object `self` (`this`) is referring to. Variables and properties are two different beasts. Not sure what you want to compare here.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I am a newb to JS. After reading your answer, PHeonix's below, and the link provided, I understand the diff. Got it !

Comment: Functions can be used as constructors. this.something is an instance specific member and members on the constructor prototype are shared among instances. Members declared as var could be available in closures to simulate private members. All explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is a local variable.  With `self.value`, you're adding a prototypical property on to the `self` variable and assigning it to `null`.

Comment: What is a "prototypical property"? How would it be different from a "normal" property?

Comment: And what is "prototyped variable scope"? *"the basic concept is that you can only access variables in the same scope or a higher scope"* That's how scope works. That has nothing to do with prototypes.

Comment: @FelixKling OP seems to not understand how scoping works in the first place - that's why I included that tidbit.

Comment: @Bergi just emphasizing that JS is a prototypical language - if you're using to working in Java or C#, it's natural that you'd be confused that you can just hang any old thing you want off of an object :)

Comment: But you seem to conflate this with prototype inheritance (somehow), which has nothing to do with the code the OP has and is more confusing than helping IMO. Scope has nothing to do with prototypes.

Comment: @FelixKling ok.  I removed it, if you think it's harmful